# update в select запросе

Tags: mysql, select, update

Есть одно задание. Имеем такой запрос:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `age`
FROM `person`
WHERE `id` = [мой код тут]
```

Я могу дописать любой код с позиции [мой код], при этом сам **SELECT** должен успешно выполниться. То есть он должен вернуть одну или более одной строк из таблицы *person*, при этом столбцы так же сохраняют свои имена.

Я делал так:

```
-1 UNION SELECT 1,2,(SELECT `secret` FROM `table` WHERE `id`=123)
```

и получался валидный код на выходе:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `age` FROM `person` WHERE `id` = -1 UNION SELECT 1,2,(SELECT `secret` FROM `table` WHERE `id`=123)
```

То есть я могу прочитать любую другую таблицу. Вопрос в другом: Могу ли я **изменить** другую/эту таблицу?
Пробовал конструкции UPDATE и INSERT, но они ничего не возвращают.

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `age`
FROM `person` WHERE `id` = -1
  UNION
SELECT 1,2,(UPDATE `table` SET `secret`='newval' WHERE `id`=123)
```

Получается, что третий элемент равен `undefined` или `null` (не знаю как правильно в mysql) и при этом выдается ошибка синтаксиса. Все-таки, что мне нужно:
Выполнить команду `UPDATE/INSERT` внутри команды `SELECT`, чтобы сам `SELECT` нам что-то вернул на выходе - только тогда самый первый `SELECT` (к которому я не имею доступа) выполнится без ошибки.

Может, у кого-то есть какие-то идеи? Спасибо.

Comment: `select 1` всегда вернет `1` =) ........а почему у вас в `update` написано `put`, а не `set`?)

Comment: Нет, выполнить update тут не получится. sql-инъекции подобного рода работают только если средство через которое вызывается запрос позволяет фактически выполнить несколько запросов разделенных точкой с запятой. тогда ставите произвольный id точку с запятой и отдельный запрос update. Только сейчас не многие функции выполнения запросов поддерживают выполнение нескольких

Comment: Кто-то ещё составляет программки с sql инъекциями? Ладно в прошлом веке у php не было запросов с параметрами, но сейчас...

Answer (score 2):

*Ответ из комментариев от [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)*

Нет, выполнить `UPDATE` тут не получится. SQL-инъекции подобного рода работают только если средство через которое вызывается запрос позволяет фактически выполнить несколько запросов разделенных точкой с запятой. Тогда ставите произвольный `id` точку с запятой и отдельный запрос `UPDATE`. Только сейчас не многие функции выполнения запросов поддерживают выполнение нескольких.